# Cопоставление location.href и массива ссылок в JS

Tags: javascript

**Суть:**
Есть блок с n-ным количеством ссылок (по типу ?go=step1, ?go=step2 и т.д.).
Есть текущий урл страницы.

**Задача:** 
Найти ссылку, идентичную текущему урлу, и вывести её на страницу.

```
function linksearch(){  
var a=location.href.search;  
var alllink = document.getElementById('divname').getElementsByTagName('a');  
var b=alllink.length;  
for (i=0; i < b; i++)  
{  
  if (alllink[i]==a)  
     document.write(alllink[i]);  
}  
}
```

Проблема: ничего не выводится (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вопрос закрыт. 
кому интересно, решение проблемы:
.search нам не нужен :)

Answer (score 1):

Решение проблемы: document.write в топку!

Answer (score 0):

используйте вместо document.write дерево элементов. document.createElement, или свойство innerHTML